# How can I run an additional function if any of my switch cases are matched?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, switch-statement

I want to run a secondary function if any of the cases in my switch statement match.

Currently, I have this:

```
flag = false
switch day
  when "Mon"
     something1()
     flag = true
  when "Tue"
     something2()
     flag = true

  if flag
    hi()
```

Is there a way to clean this up so that I don't have to use the `flag`?

Comment: Isn't that what the default case is for?

Comment: @Zenith default i think gets run if it dosen't match any of the switches.  It is like a catchall.  I guess I am looking for the opposite of the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `flag = true` in all the cases: set it in `default` clause (`else`) only.

```
shouldRun = true
switch day
  when "Mon"
     something1()
  when "Tue"
     something2()
  else 
     shouldRun = false

if shouldRun
  hi()
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion but it renames the flag rather than eliminating its usage...

Comment: While you can place `hi` calls into all the `when`s, I think this approach is cleaner. The point is not getting rid of some flag - it's about preventing code duplication. And it IS prevented here.

Comment: I agree that this is a better way to do it than having repetitive calls to the hi() function.

Comment: Either `then` or the next line break should be removed. Your current code is invalid CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell from such a thin example, but it might make more sense to re-architect things to avoid the `switch` and simply maintain a list of key/value pairs, where the keys are "Mon"/"Tue"/etc and the values are the functions to execute:

```
funcs =
  Mon: something1
  Tue: something2
  Wed: something3
  # etc ...

funcs[day]?() # invoke the matching function, if any

hi() if funcs[day] # invoke "hi" if there was a matching function
```

Invoking the function is a simple matter of indexing an array and using the `?` operator, and you can simply test for the existence of the key in the array to know whether to run `hi`.

Comment: thats a good idea.  The switch statement fits well with the current structure but this is a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

Although I would recommend using the nice suggestion about moving the flag assignment out of the switch, if your goal is to eliminate the usage of the flag variable it can be done by putting the call to the function hi() in each case where you are setting the flag as shown below:

```
switch day
  when "Mon" 
     something1()
     hi()
  when "Tue" 
     something2()
     hi()
  else 
     notHi()
```

The else case was added as it may be useful if you need to do something when your flag was set to false.